# Vb.Net Search between two dates ms access

Tags: vb.net, date, ms-access, search, between

I'm using vb.net Windows Form Application, and I have two datepicker and I want to filter between two dates...
I've tried this code :

```
Me.DBBindingSource.Filter = "[Data ardhjes] BETWEEN " & dtpDataArdhjes.Value.Date & " AND " & dtpDataArdhjesNE.Value.Date
```

And I got this error:

> Additional information: The expression contains unsupported operator
>   'Between'.

and some other codes but it does not work..
[Data ardhjes] is on table, and dtpDataArdhjes is datetimepicker from the table
and dtpDataARdhjesNe is just a dateTimepicker, sa I want to search between two dates in same column named [Data Ardhjes]
any suggestion please ?

Comment: Just use >= AND <=

Comment: Now is this error : Syntax error: Missing operand after '10' operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer:

```
Me.DBBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("[Data ardhjes] >= #{0:M/dd/yyyy}# AND [Data ardhjes] <= #{1:M/dd/yyyy}#", _
                                 dtpDataArdhjes.Value, _
                                 dtpDataArdhjesNE.Value)
```

It works great now..

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 Me.DBBindingSource.Filter = "[Data ardhjes] BETWEEN " & dtpDataArdhjes.Value.ToString("#yyyy/MM/dd#") & " 
    AND " &  dtpDataArdhjesNE.Value.ToString("#yyyy/MM/dd#")
```